# Access to music albums and metadata in iTunes on OSX? (MPMediaQuery equivalent)

Tags: macos, itunes, media

Admittedly I'm a complete noob when it comes to OSX development.  However, I've been searching for hours and can't find any help or hints.  I'm looking for a way to query albums, songs, artists etc from the iTunes library on OSX (not iOS).  Similar to MPMediaQuery class in iOS but for OSX.  Can this be done? Can you point me to a class reference or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The traditional way to access `iTunes` metatdata on a Mac is to use its Apple Events interface via `AppleScript` (or other language equivalents, like [py-appscript](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/appscript/)).  There are many references to using `iTunes` with either `AppleScript` or `appscript`, for example, [this one](http://code.google.com/p/picardplugins/wiki/AppScript).  You can use the `AppleScript Editor.app` to see the scripting dictionary for iTunes.  Here's a simple example of a query using `appscript` in Python:

```
>>> from appscript import *
>>> itunes = app('iTunes')
>>> for track in itunes.file_tracks[its.album == 'Bridge Over Troubled Water']():
...   print(track.name())
... 
Bridge Over Troubled Water
El Condor Pasa (If I Could)
Cecilia
Keep The Customer Satisfied
So Long, Frank Lloyd Wright
The Boxer
Baby Driver
The Only Living Boy In New York
Why Don't You Write Me
Bye Bye Love
Song For The Asking
Feuilles-O
Bridge Over Troubled Water (Demo Take 6)
```

Using the Apple Events interface requires that `iTunes.app` is running.  Another approach is to parse the `iTunes Music Library.xml` file which iTunes automatically creates and updates whenever metadata is changed.  That file is a documented interface to a large subset of the iTunes metadata, which is maintained in its entirety in an undocumented internal database.  The xml file is actually a `plist` file so it is easily read by the Python [`plistlib`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/plistlib.html) module:

```
>>> import os.path, plistlib
>>> lib = plistlib.readPlist(os.path.expanduser('~/Music/iTunes/iTunes Music Library.xml')) 
>>> list(lib.keys())
['Minor Version', 'Playlists', 'Features', 'Major Version', 'Library Persistent ID', 'Music Folder', 'Application Version', 'Tracks', 'Show Content Ratings', 'Date']
>>> lib['Tracks']['42527']
{'Album': 'Bridge Over Troubled Water', 'Persistent ID': 'E1C66D8F01C44BD8', 'Track Number': 1, 'Location': 'file://localhost/CD%20Cache/music/aac/Simon%20&%20Garfunkel/Bridge%20Over%20Troubled%20Water/01%20Bridge%20Over%20Troubled%20Water.m4a', 'File Folder Count': 6, 'Disc Number': 1, 'Total Time': 295826, 'Sample Rate': 44100, 'Track Count': 13, 'Genre': 'Rock', 'Bit Rate': 128, 'Kind': 'AAC audio file', 'Name': 'Bridge Over Troubled Water', 'Artist': 'Simon & Garfunkel', 'Disc Count': 1, 'File Type': 1295270176, 'Date Added': datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 13, 10, 5, 47), 'Date Modified': datetime.datetime(2008, 10, 28, 5, 59, 20), 'Library Folder Count': 5, 'Composer': 'Paul Simon', 'Year': 1970, 'Track ID': 42527, 'Size': 4941116, 'Track Type': 'File'}
```

which can then be introspected or converted to a more convenient data structure for searching.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I've also since discovered the Scripting Bridge library that appears to do something similar to what you've suggested but in Obj-C. I'm still toying with it but have a class now that reads the entire itunes Library. iTunes has to be running for it to work, which is a pity, but I'm getting closer to my end goal.